# Search Seemingly Not Working

Tags: support, search

I searched a couple of times today for an answer and received 0 results. I then asked a question, and was immediately downvoted due to it being a duplicate question. And it was almost a word-for-word duplicate. The weird part was that the search I did was almost word for word the title of the question that almost existed. So, I tried a couple more searches and received some interesting results.

I have included the 3 searches I performed to demonstrate what seems to me to be a faulty search. The first 2 searched returned 0 results, even though the second search was almost word-for-word; and the third had the answer I was looking for as the first answer.

Is this the expected search behavior?

[Search 1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20Collection%3CT%3E%20and%20List%3CT%3E)

[Search 2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20Collection%28of%20T%29%20and%20List%28of%20T%29)

[Search 3](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20collection%20list)

Comment: Please see [Is it possible to search for punctuation/special characters?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters). In brief, you can do it by [quoting the special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is+the+difference+between+%22Collection%3CT%3E%22+and+%22List%3CT%3E%22).

Comment: Also you can use Google or really any search engine. Stack Overflow ranks pretty highly in at least Google. `[query here] stackoverflow` works pretty well.

Comment: @StevenVondruska Why not just `[query here] site:stackoverflow.com`? That way 1.) "stackoverflow" is not included in your search; 2.) you *only* get results from SO

Comment: @Doorknob Wasn't sure if all search engines support the `site:stackoverflow.com` syntax. I use it all the time since Google is the only search engine I use, but just trying to make it as generic as possible.

Comment: I was already on the site, so I thought I would just use the search, rather than going back to google just to come back to the same site.

Comment: Stack exchange search isnt very good (im sorry, but its not), the "questions that may already have your answer" box when you're actually typing your question is **much** better. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187773/link-up-the-excellent-search-engine-that-gives-questions-that-may-already-have