# Why are "Questions that may already have your answer" search results better than the actual search results?

Tags: discussion, search

This is a search result for [update @ references](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=update+%40+references)

> [image]

I realize (from seeing the above search results) that my question hasn't been asked before. But as soon as I start typing, all the relevant results appear in the **Questions that may already have your answer** (which should've appeared on my first search!!)

> [image]

Just for fun, [I typed all that back into search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Update+all+%40username+mention+in+comments%2Fanswers+when+the+user+changes+their+username)

> [image]

I no longer bother with searching first and just start typing my question instead.

Why does the [Questions that may already...] functionality work better than the search bar?

Comment: Indeed, when I search for something I have to type the *exact* title and then *maybe* I will find it. I've stopped using search for anything other than popular questions, where I can use the `votes:10` filter to find them pretty quick.

Comment: Highly related; [Link up the excellent search engine that gives “Questions that may already have an answer” with the search box](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187773/link-up-the-excellent-search-engine-that-gives-questions-that-may-already-have)

Comment: I was just about to ask this same question, as nothing appeared when I searched for it, but then I found this post under "Questions that may already have an answer."