# Documenting the "search by asking"

Tags: feature-request, search, help

In mSO it was recently pointed out that [the suggested duplicates and related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268318/why-is-the-this-question-might-exist-search-better-than-the-normal-search?cb=1) sometimes provide way better results than the normal search. It was previously discussed in [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187773/link-up-the-excellent-search-engine-that-gives-questions-that-may-already-have), too, but there were no responses.

In the meantime, a trick to search that I sometimes use is to open the new question and bang in, in a more or less intelligible way, my question, and find my answers in the similar questions.

I have seen I am not the only one to use this technique, but can we advertise it somewhere?

Comment: It is not a duplicate. That question suggests adding it to the search engine, that may be technically challenging. My proposal is to just document the feature. You can use the body of your own question for it.

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: Do it yourself, by adding it to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Now as to the how: It is described in the bottom part of the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), which I quoted below for completeness.

> ### Is your question not part of the FAQ?
>
> First look at questions tagged [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to see if there is a question not in this index that might have the answer you seek. If you still can't find an answer, then see the following instructions for proposing an FAQ question.
>
> #### How can a question be added to this FAQ?
>
> - Ask only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question body.
>     The answer goes in an answer.
> - **Link back** to this index. Paste this at the end of the question:
>
>   [Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)
> - Tag as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).  When a post seems
>     to have hit a mature state, it will have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) added by a moderator.
> - Flag for a moderator to mark **community wiki**.  Any FAQ post not yet
>     community wiki should be made into a community wiki.
> - After the post has the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag added to it, add a link in the above [table of contents](/q/7931).