# Why is the SE search not as powerful/intelligent as suggestion while asking questions

Tags: feature-request, support, search

Many times when I search on Stack Overflow (or other Stack Exchange sites), I don't get any relevant results.

So, I then proceed to ask a *new question* and VOILA!!! Stack Exchange is **able** to suggest me a probably question which may already have an answer.

***Why can't the search feature do this before I try to ask a question?***

The latest example I encountered is this.

My question was (in exact words):

> Not able to use specific imports in ansible module

When I did a search in Stack Overflow, I got 0 results.
[image: No Results Page]

So, I went to add a new question. **But as soon as I just entered the question title**, this is what I got.
[image: Suggestion Page]

***And the question which is highlighted in the image matched my question exactly.***

So, why can't the `Search` feature be as good and suggest me this?

Comment: The search bar can't even manage to find the plural form when you search for the singular... Which I thought was sort of basic for search functions... particularly considering this is a site full of programmers.

Comment: Another more "senior" duplicate appears to be http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187773

Comment: @PolyGeo, yes it's a duplicate to both... But none of them seem to have any answer either. And according to [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299672/2775450), only questions with answers can be considered duplicate. Should I accept this as a duplicate?

Comment: @Codebender this does not apply for this site. Asking the same thing 10000 times won't make it happen any faster