# Stack Overflow search should resemble more the question title box search

Tags: feature-request, search, site-recommendation

I had a would-be question concerning Git. After trying some search keywords, I came to nothing.

So I wrote the question and, when I added the title:

```
Git: remote project folders mapped to separate local folders
```

I was suggested as the first entry to go to: ["Pushing to remote Git repository from local project folder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584172/pushing-to-remote-git-repository-from-local-project-folder). It is exactly what I was looking for and solved my problem.

This happens quite often to me, and it shouldn't. So I tried to investigate the subject a little and found this question:
[Related questions in "Ask Question" page is better than search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20432/233646). The accepted answer speculates our mental behaviour is different when doing the distinct searches:

> - When I use the search box, I type in some keywords, some things that might have to do with what I'm looking for.
> - When I use the question title box, I actually type in a question, so I really think about how to phrase this thing as a question.
>     I believe that this is actually the reason for the (perceived) better results: You phrase your search differently.

Well, to be free from biases, I retyped in the Stack Overflow standard search box the question above, exactly as I typed it in the title box when asking for it. To my surprise, I got zero results (not few or inconsistent ones).

Since the main search engine might be optimised for keywords, I made the comparison again with these keys:

```
Git mapped remote project local folders
```

In this case, the standard search does not bring any relevant results. If you [have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Git%20mapped%20remote%20project%20local%20folders), you will see they are substantially inconsistent with the search.

As regards the ask box, I am pointed again to:

```
pushing to remote git repo from local project folder
```

Only, using this time keywords, it is the second suggestion I get. Notably, that works even if the word "mapped" is not present in the suggested question. Beside, the first entry is:

```
git issue when add a new local folder as a remote project
```

which, while not what I am looking for, still seems very consistent with my keywords, and better than what it can be found in the standard search results.

If I couple this with my experience, it seems to me that when I use Stack Overflow as *an alternative to search engines*, the Stack Overflow standard search box works pretty well. Take, for example:

```
javascript split string comma
```

These type of searches work nicely, but the fact is that I have no question to ask here. It is just *documentation by example*. I mean that, if you forgot the syntax, Stack Overflow answer is faster to both find and read than the [official reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). For these pseudo-questions, in the unlikely case you don't find a ready-made example on Stack Overflow, you head on the reference syntax; you don't waste other people time and yours writing a question.

Instead, when you have a *real* question to ask and you want to check if someone has already asked it, then the standard Stack Overflow search does not work as well as the ask box does.

I don't know which is the rationale behind Stack Overflow standard search, by the way nowadays, given the overwhelming popularity of Stack Overflow, most of what it does, is accomplished directly by search engines indexing it. Personally I use [DuckDuckGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo) (DDG) engine and, for simple searches like above, it shows me directly the accepted Stack Overflow answer to copy and paste in my code, sparing me some keystrokes.

My conclusion is that default Stack Overflow search should work more like the ask-box search.

### Update

As noted by @Laurel, my question is linked to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187773/link-up-the-excellent-search-engine-that-gives-questions-that-may-already-have). Let me say, anyway, that  my point is not about bringing

> a little of the "New question screen" magic go into the search bar.

My point is rather about modifying the defaults.

The ask-box search is, as one might say, a smart search (based on weighing algorithms, similarities, etc.). The search-box search is simply an exact match (if I am not wrong).

So there is no way to bring some of the first one into the latter, a match whether is exact or not. However, there are a plethora of [search operators](https://stackoverflow.com/search). I haven't tried it, but there should be one to make the search-box search like the ask-box search. I think that by default the search-box search should behave *exactly like* the ask-box search does. The current exact match would instead require specific operators (e.g. quotations).

It is undisputed by many, that the ask-box search is better than the current search-box search, but the latter approach is still helpful sometimes and for that reason I think the current search behaviour should be explicitly queried to be used.

Comment: @Laurel: made an update which hopefully clarifies better my points